# Link in PDF (using wijmo PDF) does not work

Tags: pdf

In IE, the length limit of the URL is about 2048 bytes, Query string may exceed 2048 bytes.

I use lz-string to compress strings, However, the link in the pdf does not work, Or maybe use another way to compress the string?

```
var compressed = LZString.compress(query)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9e4a8dg/11

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [link](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/issues/11).

> If you want pure ASCII you can try compressToBase64